# MySQL Stored Procedure Cursor example

Tags: mysql

following code is running fine, what I need to ask how can I use a variable instead of a table name written in cursor select statement?

```
block5: begin
    declare var1 int default 0; 

    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT co_srno FROM vu_company where katscode in ('OGDC', 'LUCK', 'MCB');
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cursor1;

    my_loop: LOOP 
        FETCH cursor1 INTO var1;
        IF done THEN 
            LEAVE my_loop;
        ELSE
            set @s = concat("insert into ", @temp_table_name_scrnr_data, " (sr_no) values (", var1, ")"); 
            PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
            EXECUTE stmt; 
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
end block5;
```

Comment: Apparently the only way is by using [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082268/creating-cursor-with-dynamic-sql-in-mysql).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating cursor with Dynamic SQL in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082268/creating-cursor-with-dynamic-sql-in-mysql)

Comment: This has already been addressed several times on SO.  It's not possible without using a workaround, of which several are described in the related question above.